# Why does opening up another file with Tkinter cause another Tkinter menu to pop up?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my game, I wanted to have a launcher with some settings on it. These include volume, resolutions, battle speed, etc. When the player is done setting up, they can press the start game button to run the python file that is...well the game.
This is what the configuration menu looks like:
[image]

However, after pressing start game, instead of running the game's script, FECD.py, it opens up a blank pygame window and another tkinter menu with a few less options and a default font:
[image]

Pressing Start game on the second menu now brings up a syntax error:

```
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kayra Yorulmaz\Desktop\Resume Builders (1)\Time-Based-Strategy-Game-master\Configuration.py", line 95, in OpenServer
    exec(open("FECD.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 46, in <module>
TypeError: argument 1 must be 2-item sequence, not IntVar
```

Here's the code for the configuration menu:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as  tkFont
from tkinter import OptionMenu, Scale, HORIZONTAL, colorchooser, Button, BooleanVar, Checkbutton
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("FECD Setup")
window.geometry("320x580")
window.resizable(True, True)
ConfigFont = tkFont.Font(family="Ancient Modern Tales", size=15)


# Settings Label
Settings_lbl = tk.Label(text="Settings", fg="black", font=ConfigFont, compound="center")
Settings_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)

v = tk.IntVar()

#Resolution Label
Resolutions_lbl = tk.Label(text="Resolutions", fg="black", width=15, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
Resolutions_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Resolution Dropdown
Resolution = tk.IntVar()
Resolution.set((848, 480))
Resolutions_Drpdwn = OptionMenu(window, Resolution, (848, 480), (1280,720), (1920,1080), (2560,1440), (3840,2160))
Resolutions_Drpdwn.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#FullScreen Checkbox
FullScreen_state = BooleanVar()
FullScreen_state.set(True) #set check state
chk = Checkbutton(window, text='Choose', var=FullScreen_state)

#Volume Label
Volume_lbl = tk.Label(text="Volume", fg="black", width=15, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
Volume_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Background Music Volume Label
BGMVolume_lbl = tk.Label(text="Background Music Volume", fg="black", width=25, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
BGMVolume_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Background Music Volume Slider
BGMVol_Slider = Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, font=ConfigFont)
BGMVol_Slider.set(50)
BGMVol_Slider.pack(anchor=tk.W)

BGVolume = BGMVol_Slider.get()/10

#Sound Effects Volume Label
SFXVolume_lbl = tk.Label(text="Sound Effects Volume", fg="black", width=25, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
SFXVolume_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Sound Effects Volume Slider
SFXVol_Slider = Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, font=ConfigFont)
SFXVol_Slider.set(50)
SFXVol_Slider.pack(anchor=tk.W)

Sound_Output = tk.IntVar()
Sound_Output.set(2)

#Mono Sound Radiobutton
Mono_Sound_Rb = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="Mono", fg="black", padx=20, variable=Sound_Output, value=1, font=ConfigFont)
Mono_Sound_Rb.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Stereo Sound Radiobutton
Stereo_Sound_Rb = tk.Radiobutton(window, text="Stereo", fg="black", padx=20, variable=v, value=2, font=ConfigFont)
Stereo_Sound_Rb.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Gameplay Settings Label
Gameplay_Settings_lbl = tk.Label(text="Gameplay Options", fg="black", width=15, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
Gameplay_Settings_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Color Settings Label
Color_Settings_lbl = tk.Label(text="Menu Box Color", fg="black", width=20, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
Color_Settings_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Color Chooser Button
def choose_color():
    clr = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Select Color")
    print(clr)
Color_Chooser_btn = Button(window, command=choose_color, text="choose color", borderwidth=1, font=ConfigFont)
Color_Chooser_btn.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Battle Speed Label
Battle_Speed_lbl = tk.Label(text="Battle Speed", fg="black", width=20, height=1, font=ConfigFont)
Battle_Speed_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.W)

#Battle Speed Volume Slider
Battle_SPD_Slider = Scale(window, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, font=ConfigFont)
Battle_SPD_Slider.set(100)
Battle_SPD_Slider.pack(anchor=tk.W)

BattleSpeed = Battle_SPD_Slider.get()/200

#Game Start Button
def OpenServer():
    exec(open("FECD.py").read())

Game_Start_btn = Button(window, text="Start Game", command=OpenServer, borderwidth=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, font=ConfigFont)
Game_Start_btn.pack(anchor=tk.W)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no way we can answer this without a [mcve]. However, if you're opening a file and calling `exec`, that's a sign that you're doing something wrong. Generally speaking you should never need to use `exec` in this way. You should instead design `FEDC.py` so that you can import it and call functions within it.

Comment: I updated the code to include the full code to run the configuration, which should help creating a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: We do not need the _full_ code, we need the _minimum_ code to reproduce the problem. Creating a minimum example helps you to focus in on th root of the problem.

Comment: I tried inputting a pygame game I made for `FECD.py`, and it works perfectly. Most likely the issue is within `FECD.py`. I am thinking the issue is because you are setting some pygame window characteristics in tkinter, which might be causing an error. However, nothing is possible without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If you have found the code for the config to work properly, then the problem is in FECD of itself, which solves my question.

Comment: Try rewriting `OpenServer()` function to do `os.startfile("FECD.py")` instead of `exec(open("FECD.py").read())` you will of course need to `import os` first. You could also use subprocess instead of that if you want access to input, output, errors, etc.

Comment: I tried, but that just led to the FECD file being opened in visual studio instead of running its code. On my command line, it also started to output "(node:9240) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information"